# ¿Como redireccionar con php sin producirse lentitud?

Tags: javascript, php

Al intentar redireccionar a otra pagina y producir una alerta el periodo de carga es un poco larga como 2 seg esta en blanco  la pagina y luego me reedirige , Es bastante lento , quisiera saber si hay una via en el cual pueda evitar esto y que sea mas rapido
Ejemplo :

```html
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                                        alert("Error al insertar,el codigo de documento ya existe");
                                       window.location.href="daem.php";
                                      </script>';
```

Este codigo uso pero  es lento al redireccionar

Imagen : [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego se queda congelado 2 seg y me redirecciona

Comment: ¿Hay otro proceso en la carga? Por ejemplo, el envío de un correo, o una consulta a un servidor externo. Parece que el servidor está esperando que termine una tarea antes de redirigir. Revisa la orden de prioridad de las acciones. En PHP usa `exit;` justo después de la instrucción de redirigir, prueba colocándolo como siguiente línea a esa que publicas.

Comment: @aeportugal Produje esto y note que se puso un poco mas rapido pero aun asi se muestra la pantalla en blanco durante al menos 1 seg : echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Seleccione un período y reintente nuevamente"); window.location.href="daem.php"; </script>'; exit(); –  Luego de probarlo nuevamente se tardo lo mismo nuevamente :/